# SUM in SQL Server with PARTITION BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, rolling-sum

I have the following table

```
QuotationId QuotationDetailId   DriverId    RangeFrom   RangeTo FixedAmount UnitAmount
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    10579      7                   1           1          1     1154.00      0.00
    10579      7                   2           2          2     1731.00      0.00
    10579      11                  1           0         10     0.00         88.53
    10579      11                  2           11        24     885.30       100.50
    10579      11                  3           25        34     2292.30      88.53
```

I need to write a query in SQL Server with the following logic,

- The grouping is QuotationId + QuotationDetailId.
- For each of this block I need to sum from the second line on the value of the previous line for fixed

  ```
  Amount + UnitAmount * RangeFrom + FixedAmount of the current row
  ```

So in this case the resulting output should be

```
  QuotationId QuotationDetailId   DriverId    RangeFrom   RangeTo   FixedAmount  UnitAmount
10579             7                1           1           1        1154.00    0.00
10579             7                2           2           2        2885.00    0.00
10579             11               1           0           10       0.00       88.53
10579             11               2           11          24       1770.60    100.50
10579             11               3           25          34       7174.90    88.53
```

I've tried several queries but without success, can someone suggest me a way to do that ?

Best regards
Fabrizio

Comment: can you format the data properly so we can read it?

Comment: And show us what you have tried and found to not work?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "previous" row unless a column specifies the ordering.  What is the ordering?  And the resulting output is exactly the same as the input data.

Comment: The order by is QuotationId, QuotationDetailId, DriverId

Comment: The math doesn't look right. I think maybe you're missing `Amount`?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can do a cumulative sum.  I'm not sure exactly what the logic is you want, but this seems reasonable given the data set:

```
select t.*,
       sum(FixedAmount*UnitAmount) over (partition by QuotationId, QuotationDetailId
                                         order by DriverId
                                        ) as running_sum
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a subquery, your 'amount' column would appear on the list of columns as a query in brackets,

```
SELECT ...fields..., 
       (SELECT SUM(A.unitAmount * A.RangeFrom + A.fixedAmount) 
               From YourTable A
               WHERE A.QuotationId = B.QuotationId 
               AND   A.QuotationDetailId = B.QuotationDetailId
               AND   A.DriverId <= B.DriverId) AS Amount
        From YourTable B
```